# Showing that a subrepresentation generated by an element is actually a subrepresentation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $V$ be a representation of $G$. For $v_0 \in V$, the subrepresentation of $V$ generated by $v_0$ is constructed as $\{g \cdot v_0 | g \in G\}$.

However, I don't immediately see why $\{g \cdot v_0 | g \in G\}$ is a $G$-subrepresentation. Clearly it is $G$-invariant, but is $\{g \cdot v_0 | g \in G\}$ a subspace of $V$? Namely, how do we know that $0 \in \{g \cdot v_0 | g \in G\}$? Sorry if this is obvious.

Comment: It is not a subspace as you defined it.  You need to take the vector space spanned by such elements.

Comment: @Seth Okay, so the subrepresentation generated by $v_0$ is actually $\{g \cdot (cv_0) | g \in G, c \in F \}$, where $V$ is a vector space over field $F$?

Comment: No, it is all linear combinations of elements of the form $gv_0$

Comment: Basically, you need to take finite sums of the elements you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false.  The subrepresentation generated by $v_0$ is actually the vector space span of $\{g\cdot v_0|g\in G\}$.  This is the set of all linear combinations of such elements with coefficients in the field.